# New to credit cards

Tags: credit-card

Say If I got approved for a 0% apr for 12 months credit card with no annual fees and I used the card and paid the balance off on lets just say the 9th month so when the 13th month comes will I have a bill due if I haven't made any charges on it sense the 9th month when it was paid off?

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Can you please make it easier to understand what you're asking here?

Comment: Okay if I got approved for a credit card with 0 apr for 12 months and I use it for 9 months and pay it off and never use it again then when the 12th month comes (which is when apr start) will I still receive a monthly bill? Being I paid off the balance on the 9th month and never used the card again after it was paid off.

Answer (score 2):

The credit card company will probably send you a bill statement *every month*, whether you use the card or not, even if you don't owe them anything.  Are you planning to keep the card after you pay it off and the 12 months of no interest ends?

If the card has no interest for 12 months, why would you pay it off in 9 months?  Why not wait until the 11th month to pay off the balance?

Comment: Well I was just using 9 months as a example but yes say on the 11th month I paid it off instead, and yes I figured they wud still send a bill but would there be a payment owed?

Comment: The only way you would owe a payment is if the card charges an annual fee, or if the bank charges a minimum monthly service charge, even if you aren't charging anything.  You would have to read the cardholder agreement for details on that, or call the bank and ask.

Comment: Funny I just paid off in the 9th month.  I do like to pay off at least one month early just to have that $0 statement seeing as you could get 12 months of back interest accruing

Answer (score 1):

You will receive a monthly bill regardless of your balance.  If you follow the terms of the introductory offer to the letter, your balance at the end of the introductory offer will be zero.

Keep your eyes on that contract though.  Many of them keep track on the interest you would have been charged.  If you're one day late they may be able to charge you all the back interest.

And study how to properly use a credit card without paying interest as well.